# Post method in REST API using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, api, rest, postman

when i use following method and pass body key as `fail` (non defined key) and some value getting `pass` message in return and empty row gets inserted in table, How do I validate?

Function that I use in REST API,

```
function categories_POST() {
    $title = $this->post('title');
    $no = $this->post('no');
    $id= $this->post('id');

    $this->load->model('model_check');
    $msg = $this->model_check->addDetails($title , $no , $id);
    $this->response($msg);
}
```

My model,

```
function addDetails($x, $y, $z) {
    $check = "INSERT INTO categories (title,no,id) VALUES ('$x','$y','$z')";
    $query = $this->db->query($check);
    if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
        return "pass";
    } else {
        return "fail";
    }
}
```

Comment: What ? What are you trying to validate?  Are you trying to determine if the post data is set? Use isset. Use empty etc..

Comment: @Kisaragi i want to pass variable using `title` `no` and `id`, other than this i need to stop passing value to `addDetails` function

Comment: just add check if the variable inserting into db are blank or not first and add response for specific variable is blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quite honestly, you'd be better off using the query builder and (depending on what style you follow(fat/skinny controllers/models)) letting the model deal with `$this->post()` for processing.

Is this Phil Sturgeons/Chris A's rest server?

Something like:

```
function categories_post() {  // doesn't need to be POST()

    $this->load->model('model_check');
    $msg = $this->model_check->addDetails()
    if ($msg)
    {
        $this->response([
            'status'            => TRUE,
            'message'           => 'pass'
          ], REST_Controller::OK);
    }
    // default to fail
   $this->response([
        'status'            => FALSE,
        'message'           => 'fail'
      ], REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Your model,

```
function addDetails() {
    // this only checks to see if they exist
    if (!$this->post() || !$this->post('x') || !$this->post('y') || !$this->post('z')) {
        return false;
    };
    $insert = array(
      'x' => $this->post('x'),
      'y' => $this->post('y'),
      'z' => $this->post('z'),
    );


    if($this->db->insert('categories', $insert))
    {
        return true;

    } 
    return false;  // defaults to false should the db be down

}
```

IF you mean form_validation you can use this instead of the above.

```
function addDetails() {

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('x', 'X', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('y', 'Y', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('z', 'Z', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == true)
    {
        $insert = array(
          'x' => $this->post('x'),
          'y' => $this->post('y'),
          'z' => $this->post('z'),
        );

        if($this->db->insert('categories', $insert))
        {
            return true;

        }
    } 
    return false;  // defaults to false should the db be down

}
```

This is quite verbose, there's shorter ways to do it, but I'd rather make it easy to figure out.

Answer (score -1):

Two ways of get post values in CodeIgniter

```
$title = $this->input->post('title');
$no = $this->input->post('no');
$id= $this->input->post('id');



    $this->load->model('model_check');
    $msg = $this->model_check->addDetails($title , $no , $id);
    $this->response($msg);
```

or

```
extract($_POST);
```

Then direct access post name

```
   $this->load->model('model_check');
    $msg = $this->model_check->addDetails($title , $no , $id);
    $this->response($msg);
```

Best way is directly access post values in model files (not in controller)

Don't need the pass the POST values in model function.

If you have more queries, then ask to me

Comment: Direct Accessing Globals without filtering any values is not safe any where

Comment: I say your get values directly to model, then validate in model using isset() function